# replace and delete characters in a shell script

Tags: bash, sed

I have a shell script to automate builds of my programm. I need to transform versioning numbers like `V4_5_1-RC1` to `4.5.1-RC1`. The `V` should be removed and the `_` should be replaced with `.`. I tried several things, for example with sed:

```
$NAMEEXT = "V4_5_1-RC1"
$lffNameRSC = ${sed -e "s/V//g" <<< $NAMEEXT}
$lffNameRSC = ${sed -e "s/_/./g" <<< $lffNameRSC}
echo $lffNameRSC
```

but I'm getting errors.

```
./makerelease.sh: line 113: ${sed -e "s/V//g" <<< $NAMEEXT}: bad substitution
./makerelease.sh: line 114: ${sed -e "s/_/./g" <<< $lffNameRSC}: bad substitution
```

Comment: `$(...)` to execute command in it, not `${..}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- there should be no spaces around `=`
- there should be `$(..)` instead of `${..}` to evaluate the command
- there should not be `$` in variable assignment statement

With

```
#!/bin/bash

NAMEEXT="V4_5_1-RC1"
lffNameRSC=$(sed -e "s/V//g" <<< $NAMEEXT)
lffNameRSC=$(sed -e "s/_/./g" <<< $lffNameRSC)
echo $lffNameRSC
```

you will get

```
4.5.1-RC1
```

And, by the way, it could be done easier, like

```
$> echo "V4_5_1-RC1" | sed "s/V//g; s/_/./g"
4.5.1-RC1
```

Comment: thanks! it's been a while since i was touching shell scripting

Comment: nice answer!Variable's name should be more meaningful.

Comment: No need to `echo`... `<<<` could do it efficiently I guess... Correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) can do what you want without any external tools:

```
NAMEEXT="V4_5_1-RC1"
version=${NAMEEXT#V}     # remove the leading V
version=${version//_/.}  # replace all _ with .
echo $version            # ==> 4.5.1-RC1
```